Different results of division on M3 Mac?
Assume the following class:
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double result = Math.log(9) / Math.log(3);
        System.out.println(result);
    }
};

On a x86_64 Linux machine (Linux 6.8.10-300.fc40.x86_64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri May 17 21:20:54 UTC 2024 x86_64 GNU/Linux), I get the following result:
2.0

On an M3 Mac, I get the following instead:
2.0000000000000004

What are possible explanations of this behavior, other than a JDK bug?
The JDK version used on both machines is Temurin-21.0.3+9.

Those numbers differ by one bit in the least significant place. Time to bust out the good old Is floating-point math broken?

Feature, not a bug
The Math class states this caveat:

Unlike some of the numeric methods of class StrictMath, all implementations of the equivalent functions of class Math are not defined to return the bit-for-bit same results. This relaxation permits better-performing implementations where strict reproducibility is not required.

This means that the implementation can vary by small amounts. So it is not a bug.
Then you have to consider floating point arithmetic. We can do the real arithmetic,
log(9)/log(3) = log(3^2)/log(3) = 2 log(3)/log(3) = 2

Java is not going to make these reductions for you, it is going to calculate log(9) which does not have a non-terminating exact binary representation. Then log(3) and then perform the division. So there are a couple approximations happening.

Correct, StrictMath gives the same result on both platforms. (The M3 result.) Thank you for the answer.

I was under the impression that since JEP 306 (in Java 17) this difference should no longer exist.

@JoachimSauer I am a bit confused about that too. StrictMath.log(3) returns a different result than Math.log(3).

It seems that both of them use the strictfp mode of calculation, but StrictMath defines a specific algorithm that must be used, while Math has some freedom in the actual algorithm being used.

Of course the coolest part is Math.log just delegates to StringMath.log. Which you would expect to get the exact same results for both... The only thing I can tell is Math.log is an @IntrinsicCandidate
